# Installation of Visual Studio 2010 just hanged

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Installation of Visual Studio just hanged on Windows XP with Service Pack 3.

It stays on this way for a 2 hours now on "Executing action:DevEnv_Setup_x86_enu"

What I should do? Kill setup and try to repair later?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happened to me as well, what I did is killed the installation process and restarted the computer. Once rebooted, I started the installation and all went perfectly fine.

Comment: It worked for me. First I was trying to just restart system without success, so I had no choice other than to kill setup. Then run setup successfully after restart.